# Google Admin Directory API: Add User Employee Details

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client, google-directory-api, google-admin-settings-api

I already have a working function for adding user using Google Admin Directory:

```
string password = Random_Password();

User newuserbody = new User();
UserName newusername = new UserName();
UserOrganization newuserorg = new UserOrganization();

newusername.GivenName = GivenName;
newusername.FamilyName = FamilyName;
newuserbody.Name = newusername;

newuserorg.Department = Department;
newuserorg.CostCenter = Country;
newuserorg.Title = JobTitle;

newuserbody.Organizations = newuserorg;

newuserbody.PrimaryEmail = GivenName + "." + FamilyName + email_suffix;
//SET PASSWORD
newuserbody.Password = password;

service.Users.Insert(newuserbody).Execute();
```

This code works, but the details such as Department, Cost Center, and Title doesn't save on the record. Only First, Last name, email and password works.

---

#### Solved

Here's the code:

```
        UserOrganization[] newuserorg = new UserOrganization[1];

        newuserorg[0] = new UserOrganization();
        newuserorg[0].Department = Department;
        newuserorg[0].CostCenter = Country;
        newuserorg[0].Title = JobTitle;

        newuserbody.Organizations = newuserorg;

        newuserbody.PrimaryEmail = GivenName + "." + FamilyName + email_suffix;
        //SET PASSWORD
        newuserbody.Password = password;

        service.Users.Insert(newuserbody).Execute();
```

Comment: Don't edit your question with an answer. Add the fix as an answer and mark it as complete.

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
List<UserOrganization> l = new List<UserOrganization> { newuserorg };
newuserbody.Organizations = l;
```

Comment: I want to add employee id and some custome schemas. How can I add them?