# Google API: Getting Null on Array

Tags: c#, web-services, google-api, google-admin-sdk

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
UserOrganization[] newuserorg = new UserOrganization[10];
newuserorg[0].CostCenter = "test";
newuserorg[1].Department = "test";
newuserorg[2].Description = "test";
newuserorg[3].Domain = "demo.com";
newuserorg[4].Symbol = "TWW";
newuserorg[5].Primary = true;
newuserorg[6].Title = "title";
newuserorg[7].Type = "work";
newuserorg[8].Name = "HEY";
newuserorg[9].Location = "PH";
newuserbody.Organizations = newuserorg;
service.Users.Update(newuserbody, email).Execute();
```

I am getting null value for newuserorg[0].CostCenter

I am using **Google Admin API** and C# to update the Organization details of users.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**: It works now, I just forgot to instantiate. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Provide UserOrganization code

Comment: You never instantiate a `UserOrganization`, so you're setting properties on `null`.

Comment: Why you are creating array of `UserOrganization` ?

Comment: @RajeevKumar I am trying to update the details of user's organization (department, cost center, country etc) using Google Admin API

Answer (score 1):

Your array has 10 null slots. you need to fill them with new objects.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < newuserorg.Length; i++)
            newuserorg[i] = new UserOrganization();
```

Comment: @gherhald Start by telling what exactly are you trying to do in your code. And use more than on phrase.

Comment: @john This is what I am trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502824/google-admin-directory-api-add-user-employee-details

Comment: If you class had a constructor like below, it would be easiest:
`public class UserOrganization
    {
        public UserOrganization()
        {
        }
        public UserOrganization(string name, string address)
        {
            Name = name;
            Address = address;
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to assign values to the UserOrganization instance?

Then try:

```
UserOrganization newuserorg = new UserOrganization();
newuserorg.setCostCenter = "test";
newuserorg.setDepartment = "test";
...
...
```

Comment: I tried this one before yesterday and it seems it doesn't save on the admin side of Google.
I am getting 

"organizations":
 {
  "name": "test",
  "title": "test",
  "primary": true,
  "type": "work",
  "description": "test"
 }
,

instead of

"organizations": [
 {
  "name": "test",
  "title": "test",
  "primary": true,
  "type": "work",
  "description": "test"
 }
],

Comment: So your actual problem is that you are trying to send JSON to a service which is rejected because it is not what the API consumes? Maybe you should post a new question. Close this one and ask it properly...

Comment: Yes... That's my problem since yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502824/google-admin-directory-api-add-user-employee-details

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full constructor for what you are trying (maybe) to do:

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserOrganization[] newuserorg = new UserOrganization[10];
        newuserorg[0] = new UserOrganization("test", "test", "test", "demo.com", "test", true, "test", "test", "test", "test");
    }
}
public class UserOrganization
{
    public UserOrganization()
    {
    }
    public UserOrganization(string costCenter, string department, string description, string domain, string symbol, bool primary, string title ,string type , string name, string location)
    {
        CostCenter = costCenter;
        Department = department;
        Description = description;
        Domain = domain;
        Symbol = symbol;
        Primary = primary;
        Title = title;
        Type = type;
        Name = name;
        Location = location;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CostCenter { get; internal set; }
    public string Department { get; internal set; }
    public string Description { get; internal set; }
    public string Domain { get; internal set; }
    public string Symbol { get; internal set; }
    public bool Primary { get; internal set; }
    public string Title { get; internal set; }
    public string Type { get; internal set; }
    public string Location { get; internal set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't just edit this in to your other answer?

Comment: The question was shifting to 2 different directions: having nulls inside the array, and then, as I understood it, how to feed values efficiently into an object. Right now, I'm still not sure what was the issue and the solution, since @gherhald didn't post the working code. I also tried answering [another question asked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30530035/2381899)